# Using HttpWebRequest to POST to a form on an outside server

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I am trying to simulate a POST to a form on an external server that does not require any authentication, and capture a sting containing the resulting page.  This is the first time I have done this so I am looking for some help with what I have so far.  This is what the form looks like:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="/controller" NAME="GIN">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="JSPName" value="GIN">

Field1:
<INPUT type="text" name="Field1" size="30"
                maxlength="60" class="txtNormal" value=""> 

</FORM>
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData = "Field1=VALUE1&JSPName=GIN";
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
    // Prepare web request...
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://XXX/controller");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd(); 

    MessageBox.Show(text);

    newStream.Close();
```

Currently, the code returns "Stream was not readable".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to read the Response stream:

```
using (var resp = myRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering his rep, I think he beats a lot of people to it.

Comment: Is there any logical reason why this would not work in a controller action?

Comment: What's "this"? Ask a separate question with your specific code.

Answer (score 2):

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string postData = "Field1=VALUE1&JSPName=GIN";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

// Prepare web request...
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://XXX/");
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

string result;

using (WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to make this notify as a undiscernible edit before, which was rejected. HttpWebRequest does even not have GetResponseStream().

Comment: I don't see any "data" body attached to your example. You only specify length.