# How to POST Raw Data using C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make a POST request in which I am supposed to send Raw POST data.

Which property should I modify to achieve this.

Is it the HttpWebRequest.ContentType property. If, so what value should I assign to it.

Comment: Possible dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136857/using-httpwebrequest-to-post-to-a-form-on-an-outside-server

Comment: @Kirk Woll, Doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that. That question want's to post multipart/form-data while this seems to be sending a single stream of data.

Comment: @Jon, why do you say that?  The question I linked does not contain the string "multi" and looks pretty similar to me.

Comment: @Kirk Woll. Typo. I meant to say "post application/x-www-form-urlencoded, (or perhaps multipart/form-data) as in an HTML form". I messed up because I wasn't 100% sure of the spelling in the second case (ironically, not the one in that question, which was application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but I was aiming for full precision) and I copy-pasted over the rest :( Still, that question is about simulating html form post, and this one reads to me as wanting a single stream.

Comment: @Kirk Woll. Turns out you were right after all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public static string HttpPOST(string url, string querystring)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // or whatever - application/json, etc, etc
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());

    try
    {
        requestWriter.Write(querystring);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        requestWriter.Close();
        requestWriter = null;
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on the part where you wrote "whatever". Actually, this is the part I need clarifying. What should it be in the case of Raw Posting.

Comment: Gunner, the problem is, what do **you** mean by "raw"?

Comment: I think the word 'raw' here is internal jargon which I was told about. Basically, all I need to do is post the request. "req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";", this is working for me

Comment: Ah, I took "raw" as meaning that isn't what you needed. Kirk was right about the duplication.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the ContentType property to the mime type of the data. If its a file, it depends on the type of file, if it's plain text then text/plain and if it's an arbitrary binary data of your own local purposes then application/octet-stream. In the case of text-based formats you'll want to include the charset along with the content type, e.g. "text/plain; charset=UTF-8".

You'll then want to call GetRequestStream() and write the data to the stream returned.